# Array js with random unique figures from to

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want get array with random unique figures.

I make cycle for

```
var row = [];
var count = 10;

function getRandomArbitary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function searchRandom() {
  var rdm = Math.floor(getRandomArbitary(1, 20));

  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (rdm == row[i]) {
      searchRandom();
    }
  }
  row.push(rdm);
}
```

And then if I want 10 figures in array I make next cycle

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  searchRandom();
}

console.log(row);
```

But it doesn't work (

Comment: what exactly you want? you want to make a array with unique random numbers within a min-max range?

Comment: Yes, array with unique random numbers within a min-max range

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just make the function take the options as arguments and return the array ?

```js
function randomArray(count, min, max) {
  if (count > (max - min)) return;
  var arr = [], t;

  while (count) {
    t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    if (arr.indexOf(t) === -1) {
      arr.push(t);
      count--;
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(randomArray(10, 1, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think and i havent ran it on my system
but this should work

```
function searchRandom() {
  var rdm = Math.floor(getRandomArbitary(1, 20));

  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (rdm == row[i]) {
      searchRandom();
      return;
    }
  }
  row.push(rdm);
}
```

Notice the return statement after the nested `searchRandom()`

This will stop you from getting into incorrect cases for example lets say till now the row has [1,2]. and the next random no is 1;

Answer (score 0):

in that case why you are recursively calling the search method??

you can just loop from 1 to len (or 0 to len-1), and wait until you generated the random number that is not present simply by a while loop. here is an example

```js
var generateRandomArray = function(len, min, max) {
    if(len> (max-min)) {return;}
    var array = [],
        getRandomArbitary = function(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        },
        idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
        var num;
        while (array.includes(num = getRandomArbitary(min,max))) {}
        array.push(num)
    }

    return array;
}

console.log('Random Array of 5 element from 10 to 20: ', generateRandomArray(5, 10,20))
```